# "Object is currently in use elsewhere" exception when setting image in picturebox

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

With the title, there are several questions but none of them could help me or direct me to solve my problem.

I am building a real-time or near-real-time imaging application with C# winform.

But assigning an image to PictureBox in winform

```
pictureBox.Image = image;
```

basically gives a random exception `Object is currently in use elsewhere.` in 5-20 mins.

I searched materials on this issue but couldn't find a right solution. The error occurred when program was simply setting the image to display from a queue. So there is no way that image can be used in other thread.

At this point, I am not sure winform is right platform for an imaging application. Do I have to move to another platform such as WPF?

I need advice from experienced.

**Update:** As Nathanael pointed out, I could access picturebox from multithreads so I assumed that multithreads can access picturebox's image. So when I changed the line above to following, I don't get any error any more.

```
      private void SetImage(Bitmap image) 
      {
            if (this.pictureBox.InvokeRequired)
            {
                SetImageCallback callback = new SetImageCallback(SetImage);
                this.BeginInvoke(callback, new object[] { image });
            }
            else
            {
                pictureBox.Image = image;
            }
      }
```

Comment: am not sure how would moving to WPF solve your problem.
do you not notice this exception in a WPF application.

Comment: @VigneshNatraj That's why I am asking to experienced. Do you experience this exception in WPF as well?

Comment: I don't think moving to WPF will help as the exception indicates, if your image is used elsewhere in your program or other places you'll still get this exception. Make sure you correctly implement the IDisposable interface in class where in you interact with images and dispose the resources correctly.
Or you could just convert your image to a stream and then again reconstruct the image from the stream in the picture box.

Comment: Well, I am not sure you understand the problem. I've read many materials on this but there was not good solution. And that error was even occurred in single thread with really fast frame rate camera. That made me to ask the question. The above statement is simply to display image. Why Disposing the image would solve that problem if not the other way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you're accessing this picture box from multiple threads. WinForms uses GDI+ under the hood, which is not thread safe. WinForms does not force you to only access UI objects from the thread they were created on. It let's you do it, but you'll eventually have errors, as you've discovered.

Try posting messages to your GUI thread from your worker threads to have the GUI thread update the picture. This should solve the error you're seeing.

You'll have similar threading problems if you move to WPF. WPF strictly enforces that only the thread that created a UI object can make modifications to it. In WPF you can use the Invoke methods to have the correct thread manipulate your picture box.

Otherwise as stated the performance difference between the two won't be significant. You should consider if you need or prefer immediate mode drawing to retained mode. Forms is immediate, WPF retained.

Answer (score 1):

Both technologies should allow you to do what you want to do well.  Which is the better choice for you depedends on your previous skills and experience and the exact requirements of your project.

If you were asking about performance, if you have a fairly simple interface with not too many elements and are just basically showing one big image (which you then modify and update) you won't see much difference in performance between winforms and wpf (no 3d, no large element count).

Comment: No windows GUI API is thread-safe as they all work within a Single Threaded Apartment COM model and use a message pump to sequence messages.  All it means when they say that is that you have to interact with the GDI+ components on the GUI thread.

Answer (score -2):

```
private void ThreadSafe(MethodInvoker method)
{
    try
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            Invoke(method);
        else
            method();
    }
    catch
    { }
}

///////////////////////
pictureBox1.Image = img;
```